# Query for printing two same products as a single product on receipt?

Tags: php, sql, database

I am developing point of sale in php.I have two different sales . I sold 4 mobiles in first sale and sold 2 mobiles in second sale.The following query prints 2 items on receipt.But i want to display only one item(mobile) with quantity 6??

```css
<?php
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stock_sales where date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' ");

while ($line = $db->fetchNextObject($result)) {
?>

<tr> 
<td><?php echo $line->stock_name; ?><
<td><?php echo $line->quantity; ?></td>
</tr>}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your query to be

`SELECT stock_name, count(*), sum(quantity) AS sum_quantity FROM stock_sales where date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' group by stock_name`

Comment: i made an alias for the `count(*)` and called it `sum_quantity`, treat it like a regular column and it will contains the count of the records found, let me know if that worked or you actually want to sum the values of the column `quantity` ?

Comment: i modified the answer, i think this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much bro for your help...Now its working fine :)